# error on upgrade to 12.10

Tags: 12.04, 12.10, upgrade

Having this error message when I upgrade:

```
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)]/pool/main/d/dkms/dkms_2.2.0.3-1.1ubuntu1_all.deb File not found
Failed to fetch cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 _Quantal Quetzal_ - Release amd64 (20121017.5)]/pool/main/f/fakeroot/fakeroot_1.18.4-2_amd64.deb File not found
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: i have just tried installing updates one at a time and this seems to have worked

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are posting this "after" upgrading, not while "upgrading", type "Software Sources" in the `dash`, and in the second tab in it, that reads "Other Software", uncheck the first line "cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.10 *Quantal Quetzal* ....(and so on)" and close and then do a `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.